# Can the "ol-layerswitcher" control be configured to indicate if a layer is not visible due to minZoom/maxZoom?

Tags: openlayers, layers

I have the OpenLayers [layerswitcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol-layerswitcher) control implemented and working.  However, there does not seem to be any visual cue to the user that the layer is not visible due to minZoom/maxZoom (e.g. my Parcels layer has a minZoom of 14).

Does the control have a way to configure this behavior?

**Existing Code:**

```
  private _parcelLayer = new TileLayer({
    name: "Parcels",
    title: "Parcels",
    minZoom:14,
    visible:true,
    source: new OlXYZ({
      url: sourceUrl,
      maxZoom: 19
    })
  } as BaseLayerOptions);  


.
.
.



this.map = new OlMap({
  target: "map",
  layers: [baseMapLayerGroup, this._parcelLayer ],
  view: new OlView({
    center: [-8622609.656113915, 4480804.736605563],
    zoom: 7
  }),
  controls: defaultControls().extend([
    new ZoomToExtent({
      extent: [-9752043.186055679, 4046642.415945762, -7493176.1261721505, 4914967.057265365]
    })
  ])
});

setupLayerSwitcher();

.
.
.


private setupLayerSwitcher() {
    const layerSwitcher = new LayerSwitcher({
        reverse: true,
        groupSelectStyle: "group"
    });
    this.map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
}
```

[image]

```
"ol-layerswitcher": "^3.8.3",
"ol": "^6.4.3",
```

Comment: Coding questions on GIS SE site should have relevant existing code included. Please add relevant code, otherwise you risk your question will be closed as not compliant the site policy.

Comment: @TomazicM It was more a question about the control capability and configuration as opposed to actual coding, but I've added code snippets (which are basically out of the layerswitcher and do work correctly).

Comment: `minZoom`/`MaxZoom` was a recent addition to the layer options in OpenLayers so the LayerSwitcher only works as you expected if you specify `minResolution`/`maxResolution`.  You can use `view.getResolutionForZoom()` to get the resolutions to specify,

Comment: @Mike Thanks! Works like a charm.  If you make it an answer, I'll upvote/accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minZoom`/`MaxZoom` was a recent addition to the layer options in OpenLayers so the LayerSwitcher currently only works as you expected if you specify `minResolution`/`maxResolution`. You can use `view.getResolutionForZoom()` to get the resolutions to specify,